# Execute get_supply function within contract

Tags: smart-contract

I want to execute get_supply from currency.hpp.

Here is the definition:

```
asset get_supply( symbol_name symbol )const {
        accounts t( _contract, symbol );
        return t.get(symbol).balance;
     }
```

Currency constructor:

```
currency( account_name contract )
         :_contract(contract)
         { }
```

I am trying like that:

```
void get_supply(extended_asset mytoken) {
        extended_symbol es = mytoken.get_extended_symbol();
        auto sym = es.symbol;
        auto curr = currency(N(mytoken.token));
        auto stats = curr.get_supply(sym);
    }
```

mytoken.token -> custom token contract (copy of eosio.token)

I am getting error:

> Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure Error Details:
>   assertion failure with message: unable to find key

Anyone  knows how  to use this function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs on the line:

`return t.get(symbol).balance;`

The reason is that the primary key in the multi-index table does not exist.
This means that you must have not added the symbol to the `accounts` table. You would have to do this by using the `multi_index::emplace` function before trying to access the table entry.

Presumably it could also be that the values you are using for the contract and scope of the table are incorrect.